# Почему кошку назвали кошкой

Tags: этимология

Прочитал в ответах – «потому, что кошку назвали кошкой», стало интересно, а как на Руси называли или называют животину, именуемую «кошкой»?
В русском языке слово "кошка" - производное от слова "кот". 
В талышском языке, полагаю и в роськом, кот, кошка – кыты. 
Дословно – маленький (кутенок у собаки, котенок у кошки и т. п). Одним словом, детеныш.
Окот – процесс появления на свет «кыты» (кт).
Звук "ы" в талышском языке является связующим. 
Получается, что нет у бедной кошки своего имени. 
Просто - маленькая, махоня?
Спасибо.

Comment: А что это за язык — роський? Википедия его не знает.

Comment: Может быть, *русинский*?

Comment: Помогу Автору. «...носители роського мировозрения, связывая себя со славными предками и духовными учителями волхвами–украми, естественно называют себя не только росами, но и украинцами (последователями волхвов-укров), а свой роський язык – украинским». Зачем он держал в себе знание, что самый «близкий к роському» — язык Волыни I тыс. н.э., не имею понятия.

Comment: Мек кажется, что очередное явление апологета Великоталышской идентичности "роським", как и его предшественники, пренебрежительно именует русский.

Comment: user244413 Читайте книги ( в любом виде) - источник знаний.

Comment: Victor Bazarov Попробуйте объяснить этнонимы русь, русин и т.п. А вот рось имеет ясное значение. Уже писал

Comment: Рось - исторический этап становления государства Российского. Не зная, не понимая культуры основателя государства, нечего и говорить о неких особенностях русского этноса, мира. Я намеренно не пишу о роли роси в деле строительства России. Рось- это вовсе не непонятно какие "укры".  А вот о  близости культур Волыни и Роси, Росалани, можно было бы побеседовать, понятно, не здесь. Ведь и Каспийское море в свое время называлось Хвалынским. Роський язык, в основе- язык даев. Потому так много роських слов в современном талышском языке, что как и роський сложен из местного языка и языка пришлых даев.

Comment: А спросил я про кошку, всего -то. Мне интересно кошачье имя Алабрыс. И почему кошке - брысь, птахам - кыш, а с собакой, лошадью, медведем только по -человечьи? Только ли из уважения  к габариту изгоняемового?

Comment: behemothus Креститесь, или что там у вас делают, когда кажется.

Answer (score 10):

**"В талышском языке..."**

Вы хоть знаете, что это за язык, насколько он далёк как географически, так и по классификации от русского? Там никакой взаимосвязи не может быть. Всё дело в том, что в последнее время везде идёт такая тенденция - героизировать историю своего малюсенького народа, преувеличить её роль в истории человечества. И вот именно из этих соображений этимологию некоторых слов русского языка или языка другого многочисленного народа начинают приписывать к своему малочисленному, "но гордому народу" представители нацменьшинств.

Я сам по национальности лезгин и к своему стыду должен признаться, что у нас за последнее время появилась плеяда "гениальных" учёных, "доказавших", что именно от лезгин произошли народы Древней Греции, ибо их самоназвание "пелазги" и название нашей нации "лезги" не являются случайными... Короче, советую не доверять таким дешёвым уловкам.

Comment: Не совсем по теме тут, но позицию вашу вполне разделяю.

Answer (score 6):

Кошка. Вост.-слав. В памятниках отмечается с XIV в. До этого времени употреблялось сущ. котъка, являющееся образованием с суф. -ъка (совр. -ка) от котъ и сохранившееся в иных слав. яз. (ср. болг. котка, польск. kotka). Совр. кошка, вероятно, является производным с суф. -ка от ласкат. коша, представляющего собой образование от котъ с суф. -ша (ср. Маша, Саша и т. п.).

“Краткий этимологический словарь русского языка” Н. М. Шанского, В. В. Иванова, Т. В. Шанской.

Comment: Так "котька" это-то известно... (Только там не ер, а ерь далжен быть по логике перехпда Ш<Ть)  Вопрос, если он и есть, насчет общности "кошка" и "котится" "окот". Согласен с Бегемотусом, ласкательное "коша" здесь совершенно лишнее, за уши притянутое.

Answer (score 1):

А английское <<**CAT**>> =кот тоже вышло из *талышского* ?!  Логичнее взять , что тут обще-иноевропейский корень . И совершенно прав **@Наби Мусаибов** - нечего всюду  протаскивать свои малые народы , особенно там , где они в принципе не могут присутствовать . /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// P.S. И небольшая ремарочка к ответу @Наби Мусаибов , которая , впрочем , не меняет его мысль : пеласги и лелеги в Древней Греции считались , так называемыми , *до-лунными* народами , жившими на территории Эллады изначально , до появления там греконосых эллинов . Эллины никогда не считали пеласгов и лелегов своими предками или , хотя бы , сородичами . От пеласгов произошло название полуострова Пеллопонес .

Answer (score 1):

Кошка произошло напрямую от "котка"<"кот", "котя". Объяснения Шанского, предполагающего посредство "коши" непоследовательны, сама это "коша" выглядит надуманной. Какие еще Маши-Саши в XIV-то веке? К тому же есть "киска", "кися" зачем еще "коша"? 
А смягченое "Т" в "котя" вполне могло породить "кощька" с последующей 
"кошкой".

Фасмер логичнее.

Этимология

Происходит от существительного кот, далее от праслав. *kotъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., церк.-слав. котъка (Пов. врем. лет), русск. кот, укр. кіт (род. п. кота́), болг. кот, сербохорв. стар. ко̑т, чешск., польск., н.-луж. kot. По-видимому, заимств. из народнолат. cattus «дикая кошка» (начиная с IV в. н. э.). Заимствование из готск. *katts весьма сомнительно; неприемлемо и объяснение из греч., поскольку ср.-греч. κάττα известно только с VI в. Предположение о заимствовании из ниж.-нем. katt (вопреки Кнутссону) неправдоподобно, если принять во внимание большое распространение этого слова в слав. языках; по культурно-историческим соображениям невероятно также исконнослав. происхождение или заимствование в балт.-слав. эпоху. Источник названия этого животного безуспешно искали в кельтск. и нубийском. Следует отделять от котиться. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0

Обратите внимание, Фасмер предостерегает от смешения с "котиться", "окотиться", "окот". Вот этот морф может быть родственным словам, обозначающем на разных ИЕ-языках детеныша. 
//===================
Слово: котиґться

Ближайшая этимология: "рожать детенышей (о кошках, куницах, хорьках, зайцах, овцах, козах)", укр. котиґтися, кiтнаґ (*котьна) "беременная (о животных)", об-кiґт, род. п. об-коґту "окот (овец)", болг. коґтя се (котиґл) "котиться", котиґло "место окота, окот, потомство", сербохорв. (о)ко°ти?м, ко°тити се "щениться, котиться, рожать (в диал. -- обо всех животных)", ко°тило "место окота", ко?т, род. ко?та "выводок (птенцов), с-ко?тна "беременная (о собаке, лисице и др. животных"), словен. kotiґti "котиться", ko°t, род. п. koґtа "выводок, приплод", sko°t, род. п. skoґtа "детеныш, потомство", чеш. kotiti sе "котиться" польск. kocicґ sie§ "котиться, ягниться и т. д.", kotna "беременная, суягная", wуkоt "окот", в.-луж. (wо) koґcicґ sо, koґcґowacґ "забеременеть".

Дальнейшая этимология: Первонач. знач. "рожать" (о животных), связь с кошками явно вторична; см. Вальде--Гофм. (1, 183), Маценауэр (48) против Миклошича (Мi. ЕW 135), Бернекера (1, 590); эта связь обусловлена созвучием с кот (см.). Родственно лат. catulus "детеныш, щенок", catellus "собачка", умбр. katel, род. п. katles "catulus", др.-исл. ha?na ж. "козленок", ср.-в.-н. hatele ж. "коза", швейцарско-нем. hatle "коза"; см. Вальде--Гофм., там же; Бернекер, там же; Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 103.

http://vasmer.narod.ru/p315.htm

Здесь (ґ - знак ударения).

Answer (score 1):

Русские слова *кошка* и *кот*, безусловно, связаны в том числе и с английским словом *cat*. Происхождение этого слова очень хорошо проясняет английский этимологический онлайн-словарь:
['cat' on etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cat&searchmode=none).

> **cat (n.)** Old English *catt* (c. 700), from West Germanic (c. 400-450),
>   from Proto-Germanic **kattuz* (cognates: Old Frisian *katte*, Old Norse
>   *köttr*, Dutch *kat*, Old High German *kazza*, German *Katze*), from Late
>   Latin *cattus*.
>
> The near-universal European word now, it appeared in Europe as Latin
>   *catta* (Martial, c. 75 C.E.), Byzantine Greek katta (c. 350) and was in
>   general use on the continent by c. 700, replacing Latin *feles*.
>   Probably ultimately Afro-Asiatic (compare Nubian *kadis*, Berber
>   *kadiska*, both meaning "cat"). Arabic *qitt* "tomcat" may be from the
>   same source. Cats were domestic in Egypt from c. 2000 B.C.E., but not
>   a familiar household animal to classical Greeks and Romans. The nine
>   lives have been proverbial since at least 1560s.
>
> The Late Latin word also is the source of Old Irish and Gaelic cat,
>   Welsh *kath*, Breton *kaz*, Italian *gatto*, Spanish *gato*, French *chat*
>   (12c.). Independent, but ultimately from the same source are words in
>   the Slavic group: Old Church Slavonic *kotuka*, *kotel'a*, Bulgarian
>   *kotka*, Russian *koška*, Polish *kot*, along with Lithuanian *kate* and
>   non-Indo-European Finnish *katti*, which is from Lithuanian.  Extended
>   to lions, tigers, etc. c. 1600. As a term of contempt for a woman,
>   from early 13c. Slang sense of "prostitute" is from at least c. 1400.
>   Slang sense of "fellow, guy," is from 1920, originally in U.S. Black
>   English; narrower sense of "jazz enthusiast" is recorded from 1931.
>
> *Cat's paw* (1769, but *cat's foot* in the same sense, 1590s) refers to
>   old folk tale in which the monkey tricks the cat into pawing chestnuts
>   from a fire; the monkey gets the nuts, the cat gets a burnt paw. *Cat
>   bath* "hurried or partial cleaning" is from 1953. *Cat burglar* is from
>   1907, so called for stealth. *Cat-witted* "small-minded, obstinate, and
>   spiteful" (1670s) deserved to survive. For *Cat's meow*, *cat's pajamas*,
>   see ***bee's knees***.

Таким образом, где-то в 75-м году нашей эры это слово появилось в латыни (catta), откуда и перешло в другие европейские (в том числе славянские и русский) и афро-азиатские языки (в том числе и арабский), причём независимым образом по всем трём направлениям. И пришло оно даже в финский язык не индоевропейской, а финно-угорской группы (из литовского).

Comment: Хоть и занудно, но в целом правильно)))

Comment: )))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Корень в слове (морфема) — это согласный звук (фонема), минимальная смыслообразующая часть слова.
Сколько в самой простой (короткой) форме конкретного слова ("первичной" лексеме) согласных звуков (фонем)- столько в этом слове и КОРНЕЙ.**
Есть много деталей с ЙОТИРОВАННЫМИ звуками и т. д.
Но общая схема (тезисно) - такая и она работает !

Очень и очень высоко вероятно, что те мировые столпы лингвистики (из эпохи "ИНТЕРНЕТА НЕТ"), коих привыкли цитировать приличные лингвисты, при использовании современных IT возможностей - написали БЫ ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНО ИНЫЕ ЭТИМОЛОГИИ.

В этимологических исследованиях целесообразно уравнять в значениях термины "Корень в слове" и "Морфема". Термин МОРФЕМА можно не использовать - хватит понятия "Корень".
Корни (согласные фонемы - консонанты) - они всеобщие - они основа Языка-Речи, как СМЫСЛО-СОДЕРЖАЩЕЙ (смысло-передающей) СТРУКТУРЫ-СИСТЕМЫ (технологии).

Любая теория - условно верна.
Выбирайте то - что понятнее удобнее продуктивнее полезнее. 
"Странно", что большинство логофилов не хотят знать - на Востоке (например в Индии) понятие Корень (основа слова) традиционно означает "ЗВУК-СМЫСЛ".

Если вы не видите причин для замены существующего определения "Корень слова" - 
попробуйте самостоятельно определить корни в словах ПОТОП ТОПОТ КАТОК ТИКАТЬ (бежать).

Факты в пользу правомерности (полезности) нового определения - См. статьи "Этимология ..."

---

Лингвистика уже вполне доказала общее происхождение почти всех известных языков и выяснять чей язык старше и ближе к пра или прото-языку всех народов - это сомнительный подвиг.
Грамотный языкастый находчивый и речистый лингвист (филолог) найдёт массу аргументов для любого слова (корня) в пользу его истока почти в любом языке.
Но почему вещи называются так как они называются, а не иначе - этимология не сообщает. 
Да, мощный этимолог раскопает самые древние письменные или фольклорные артефакты бытия для какого то слова (корня, морфемы). И дальше найдутся десятки других супер-этимологов, которые приведут сотни своих контр доводов, и так за далью даль. И дальше тайна (Бог).

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем появились привычные нам слова-понятия КОТ (англ. Cat) и КИТ (морской), были созвучные современным, слова типа К*Т (Т*К).
Кот Кит Ток и пр. произшли от звуков-корней К и Т.
Согласные фонемы - это реальные первичные ВСЕОБЩИЕ пракорни-морфемы, и естественно что гласные в словах типа К*Т (Т*К) в одном и в разных языках бывают почти любые. Но при этом, благодаря относительному постоянству исходных согласных звуков, изначальные смыслы-значения пракорней (исходных согласных фонем) в таких словах, обычно (более-менее) сохраняются. И часто такое прямое смысловое родство-связь между разными словами с общими пракорнями (согласными фонемами) явно и очевидно.

Логические построения позволяют определить основные значения наших "Пра-Котов-Китов", и понять - как древние значения праслов развились до современных. 
Конечно, тут почти всё зависит от корректности исходных посылов, и чем ближе они к реальности - тем более верными могут стать выводы. Попробуем проверить...

Основные значения праслова "*К*Т*" : 
- ограниченное (усечённое) пространство-объём. 
- относительно малый (ограниченного размера или количества) объект.
- коническая угольная форма (предмет). 
Реально, здесь мы имеем дело с одним общим комплексным смыслом-значением, которое в обобщённом виде можно выразить формулой - "Коновая Твердь" или Ограниченное Пространство-Объект.